# How to right-align a number on the last digit, allowing any text (e.g. %, /day, /ea) to exceed boundary

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to list a vertically aligned set of numbers with the 0s digit perfectly aligned. This means any number with a fractional piece (.0001) would need to be shifted to the right so the fractional piece exceeds the container boundary. Likewise, a percentage like 58% would need to shift the % out of the container. Or something like "532,532/day" would need to shift /day out of the container. And so on. One of the problems I've encountered using CSS `right:` or `transform: translateX()` is that even in `em` units it doesn't seem to always be the # of characters I would think to achieve visual alignment. That probably is due to varying width of characters. And while I could maybe get that to work for %, it wouldn't work for a varying length fractional piece.

Examples:

```
134,435,234
     23,135
         22
        513.0353
         85%
      2,532/day
          8/ea
```

Is this doable in CSS? If not, is there a simple, concise (elegant) Javascript option? I know I could cobble together something ugly in Javascript, but looking for elegance.

Comment: The only way I've done this is to split them into separate containers, with the number portion in a left container that's align-right, and a right container with the rest which is align-left. Would that suit your needs?

Comment: That would be pretty ungainly, having to parse strings like that and split them up.

Comment: Yes indeed (well, not *that* ungainly, but still, not ideal). The other way I've done it is with a monospaced font.

Comment: So I take it the answer is "No", there is no elegant solution.

Comment: Hard to prove a negative, there could easily be something I don't know about.

Comment: FWIW, one of the inelegant solutions, using CSS grid: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/1uhpecga/1/ Sadly, if you select a full line and copy it, it gets a line break in the middle (as with a table). Was kind of hoping that wouldn't happen with CSS grid and spans, but it does (at least on Chromium browsers).

Comment: I didn't direct my comment to you, I was responding to whomever closed the question as a duplicate. The question I seemed to have duplicated has answers but no accepted answer, and the gist of that post seems to be "No, you have to do this the hard way". Which is okay I suppose. I can do that... it was worth checking.

Comment: I didn't take any comment above as...targeted... :-) (Maybe I missed something that's since been removed?) Hope the fiddle is useful. Happy coding!